# Counter in double loop with counting in both internal and external for

Tags: python, algorithm, nested-loops

I would like to know if there is a well-known formula for the following way of counting:

```
count = 0
for i in range(n):
   for j in range(m):
      count = count + 1
   count = count + 10
```

Many thanks in advance,

Cayo

EDIT 1:

Thanks Ernest, you are right, but that is not really the problem. Sorry, I was not clear enough, let me explain better my problem. I don't just want to count, I need use this counter inside the inner loop. I have a 2D flatten array and I want to access just a sub-2D-region of this array. So, actually, what I am doing is:

```
count = 0
for i in range(n):
   for j in range(m):
      big_flatten_array(count) = value
      count = count + 1
   count = count + 10
```

EDIT 2: 
It doesn't work just using

```
count = i * 10 + j
```

Try checking the values:

```
count = 0
for i in range(3):
   for j in range():
      k = i * 2 + j
      vec[k] = count
      vec2[k] = i * 10 + j
      count = count + 1
   count = count + 10
```

And you will see the vec and vec2 are not the same...

Comment: what you want to achieve? give example

Comment: Please feel free to add more details about your problem : what is the goal of this algorithm ? What is the context ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider that the line `count = count + 10` didn't exist, then it would simply be:

```
count = i*m + j
```

Consider n = 3, and m = 3
So the count values are like 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ..
once you add the line `count += 10`, you're simply adding multiples of 10 to the count value each time the outer loop finishes.

0, 1, 12, 13, 24, 25... or 0, 1, 10 + 2, 10 + 3, 20 + 4, 20 + 5...

so the expression becomes

```
count = (10*i) + (i*m+j)
```

And you can get all the count values like so:

```
count = [(10 * i) + (i * m + j) for i in range(n) for j in range(m)]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is really simple solution

```py
count = n*(10+m)
```

Comment: This is the actual correct answer. Best would be to also show how you deduced it.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try. If I understand correctly you just need current (not final) value of `count` inside the loop. So this should do:

```py
# In the inner loop    
count = i * 10 + j
```